# Classe Pessoa > Pessoa Jurídica > Pessoa Física. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou desenvolvendo um `APP` em `Rails`, e me surgiu a seguinte dúvida referente a classe Pessoa.

A estrutura dessas classes estão assim:

```
Pessoa { tipo, status }
PessoaJuridica { razãoSocial, nomeFantasia, CNPJ, IE, IM }
PessoaFisica { nome, apelido, CPF, RG }
```

Na minha `view` de Pessoa no `_form.html.erb` eu tenho um `radio_button` para selecionar o tipo de pessoa a ser cadastrada(`Fisica ou Juridica`), mas estou em dúvida como criar os campos do form. Nesse caso o relacionamento é `has_one` de Pessoa para `PessoaFisica/Juridica`, como que eu criaria esse _form para ter os campos tanto da tabela de `PessoaFisica` como de `PessoaJuridica` e alterá-los dependendo da seleção do `radio_button` ?

Eu pensei em criar dois `_forms` um para pessoa física, e outro pra jurídica e coloca-los na `view` com um `style display: none`; e mostrá-los com `jQuery` quando forem selecionado no `radio_button`, isso é válido ? E como ficaria o `controller` de Pessoa ao salvar o cadastro, como farei pra identificar na hora do Create, se é pessoa física ou jurídica ? e em qual Model salvar ?

Agradeço desde já, Abraços.

**EDIT**

Consegui criar o `_form` com todos os campos mostrando apenas os campos que o usuário seleciona com o `radio_button`. O problema agora é ao salvar o cadastro, como na prática eu tenho os campos de dois Model no `_form` apenas 'escondendo'(.hide()) os campos que não são da seleção do `radio_button`, quando eu confirmo o cadastro, está salvando uma `pessoa_juridica` e uma `pessoa_fisica`, e a que não foi selecionada no `radio_button` fica com os campos todos em branco (""). Como resolvo isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode, antes de salvar - no controller, verificar se os campos estão vazio e não salvar se estiverem dessa forma.

Ou talvez possa usar a seguinte expressão no seu model-parent:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :model-child, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['name'].blank?}
```

Qualquer coisa poste seu controller e seus models que eu posso ver se tenho conhecimento para te ajudar. Sou novato ainda.